# throw kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException when go to another screen

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

Android Studio 3.6

on one screen I polling by coroutine like this:

```
 fun initPoll() =       
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            var errorMessage = ""
            try {
                while (true) {
                    val balanceValue: BigDecimal = TransportService.getBonuse()
                    delay(1000)
                }
            } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                Debug.e(
                    TAG,
                    "initPoll: error_message = ${e.message}, ex = $e"
                )
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                Debug.e(
                    TAG,
                    "initPoll: error_message = ${e.message}, ex = $e"
                )
            } 
        }
```

In transport service:

```
suspend fun getBonuse() =
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                // some code here
            } // Dispatchers.Main
```

In Activity :

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
private lateinit var poll: Job

 override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        poll.cancel()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        poll = mainViewModel.initPoll()
    }
```

It work fine. But when I go to another screen (Activity) it throw

```
02-12 11:34:17.115 E/com.myproject.MainViewModel(17685): initPoll: error_message = StandaloneCoroutine was cancelled, ex = kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: StandaloneCoroutine was cancelled; job=StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@aa5d4a1
```

After go to another screen I need to stop polling.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what's supposed to happen? You navigate away from an activity, its coroutines get cancelled by your explicit `poll.cancel()` call. Also you shouldn't catch `CancellationException`s, that swallows cancellation and leaks coroutines.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik After go to another screen I need to stop polling.

Comment: And the technical way you achieve it is by cancelling the coroutine. Coroutine cancellation works by throwing `CancellationException` and you are catching it instead of letting it through.

Answer (score 11):

Your current implementation of coroutine is bounded to the lifecycle of ViewModel, and `viewModelScope` [cancels after ViewModel has been cleared up](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel.kt) (what is happening after you open another Activity).

So if your goal is to stop polling bonuses after you navigate to another Activity you don't need to implicitly stop the coroutine with `poll.cancel()`, just let `viewModelScope` do it's job. Otherwise, if you want to continue polling after ViewModel is cleared, consider using some upper (probably Global) scope.

If you want to avoid `JobCancellationException` in your code - instead of try/catch consider using [CoroutineExceptionHandler](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-exception-handler/) as an addition to your coroutine context, it's designed to handle uncaught exceptions in coroutines and ignore cancelled exceptions.

Comment: Do you have an example of CoroutineExceptionHandler?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky just add it to your context scope like scope.launch(contextProvider.IO + handler) {
            .... some coroutines launches here
}
    private val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
        logError(e.message)
        // handle error like in a catch block
    }

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got the exception "kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: StandaloneCoroutine was cancelled" when scrolled a `RecyclerView` with pagination. When it loaded then next page of data, I clicked an item. It launched `coroutineContext.cancelChildren()` and started another request.

So, when I tried to load a new portion of items, it cancelled the request and fell into `try-catch`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `coroutineScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()`

If you use `coroutineScope.cancel()`, corroutine couldn´t be launched again due its canceled.

If you use `coroutineScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()` you are canceling process under coroutineScope